# yui3's version of jquery's .width()

Tags: yui, yui3

How do you calculate the width (in pixels) of an element in yui3?  I have tried `.getComputedStyle("width")` and `.get('offsetWidth')` and neither return the correct results, possibly because the div doesn't have a CSS width set on it.

Comment: Closing.  OP says it was his error.

Answer (score 1):

It's working fine for me [here](http://jsfiddle.net/99xRa/1/), could you provide an example where it fails?

Maybe you're expecting it to include padding/border? JQuery's .width() doesn't include those either, but perhaps that's where the confusion lies.